# How to change values in a column from object type to float. for Example, "'€220 M" to 220,000,000?

Tags: pandas

I have a column with data as:

```
1           77M
2        118.5M
3           72M
4          102M
5           93M
6           67M
```

I need to change this to its numerical value as:

```
77,000,000
```

and so on.

I have tried different ways but could not come up with a definite solution.

Answer (score 0):

okay this should work

```
(df[1].str.replace('M','').astype(float) * 1000000).astype(int).astype(str).apply(lambda x : x[:-6]+','+x[-6:-3]+','+x[-3:])
```

**Output**

```
0     77,000,000
1    118,500,000
2     72,000,000
3    102,000,000
4     93,000,000
5     67,000,000
Name: 1, dtype: object
```